# Allocating space for upper triangular matrices in algebraic notation

Tags: c, matrix, malloc, free, algebra

I'm working on a project (written in C) involving matrix factorization and I need some help.
My objective is to allocate memory for an upper triangular matrix and I want to access it via algebraic row and column notation (i.e. i,j in `{1,2,...,n}` instead of i,j in `{0,1,...,n-1}`).
For example, in a 5x5 matrix I should be able to access the [3][4] element if I input `matrix[3][4]`.

My code for a non-algebraic index upper triangular matrix looks like this:

```
double** malloc_sup_matrix (int n)
{
    double**    L;
    int         i;

    L = (double**)malloc((n)*sizeof(double*));

    if(L == NULL)
        printerror("allocating space for the matrix (rows).");        

    for(i = 0;  i < n;  i++)
    {
        L[i] = (double*)malloc((n-i)*sizeof(double));
        if(L[i] == NULL)
            printerror("allocating space for the matrix (cols).");
        L[i]-=i;
    }
    return L;
}
```

My code for the algebraic index one (I'm not checking if the allocated space is null yet, I'll do it when I stop messing around with this):

```
    int**   m;
    int     i, n;

    n = 10;

    m = (int**)malloc((n+1)*sizeof(int*));
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        m[i] = (int*)calloc((n+1)-(i),sizeof(int));
        m[i] -= i;
    }

    m--;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        m[i]--;
    }
```

It works just the way I want it, **but** I have issues when freeing the space I've used. This is the way I'm doing it:

```
    for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        m[i]++;
    }    

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        m[i] += (i);
        free(m[i]);
    }
    m++;
    free(m);
```

Do you guys have any suggestions? Thank you so much in advance ^^.

Comment: "but I have issues when freeing the space I've used." Please be explicit. What is the issue you are having?

Comment: I would suggest to rethink your storage concept. Rather than allocating space for `n` differently sized vectors (which can lie anywhere in the memory), you can also use one vector of dimension `n(n+1)/2`. This has several advantages, among them interoparability with Blas and Lapack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a problem on this line:

```
m--;
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    m[i]--;
}
```

You're decrementing m, but then go ahead and index it from 0 ... I guess you may end up messing up the heap structures.

I managed to have your code valgrind error-free like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int**   m;
    int     i, j, n;

    n = 10;

    m = (int**)malloc((n+1)*sizeof(int*));
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        m[i] = (int*)calloc((n+1)-(i), sizeof(int));
        m[i] -= i;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        m[i]--;
    }

    m--;

    /* Access it like m[1][1] ... m[n][n], m[i][j] (with i <= j) */

    /*
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        for (j = i; j <= n; j++) {
            m[i][j] = i+j;
        }
    }
    */

    m++;

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        m[i]++;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        m[i] += (i);
        free(m[i]);
    }

    free(m);

    return 0;
}
```